# PHP / Regex : match json inside json

Tags: php, regex, json

Just a quick regex question...hopefully

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
$string = 'some text [ something {"index":"{"index2":"value2"}"}]   [something2 {"here  to be":"more specific"}]';
```

I want to be able to get the value:

```
{"index":"{"index2":"value2"}"}
```

But all my attempts at matching (or replacing) keep giving me:

```
{"index":"{"index2":"value2"}

preg_replace('/\[(.*?)({.*?[^}]})*?\]/is', "", $string);
```

Here I'm matching the whole square bracket area, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.

The negation of the "do not match }" doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Maybe I just need an OR in there or something.

Well, thanks if you have time to answer.

The $string could contain multiple instances of the {} so a greedy regex won't work....that I know of.

Comment: In general, matching something like that involving matched open/close delimiters (curly braces or square brackets) cannot be done with a regular expression at all. If your strings have some other reliable delimiters *around* the JSON segment, it might be possible.

Comment: Man, that sucks.  I saw something saying that on a post for C#.  If this was you, would you explode and match inside each array segment?  Or is this just not a good idea at all?

Comment: @Senica: Why not parse the JSON properly with a JSON parsing function, like a sane person? That's what those functions _exist for_. It's the entire purpose of the whole JSON system.

Comment: maybe this will help - http://rubular.com/r/RXx4Dghrwn

Comment: @Tomalak, How would JSON parsing functions help me if I don't have the JSON separated first?

Comment: @nash....that certainly works, but as I mentioned to Shakti below, the $string is just for example purposes.  There could be multiple {}s in the actual context

Comment: @Senica @Tomalak Geret'kal I totally agree, what is creating that string?  There is functionality in PHP out there which takes care of JSON, why are you trying to reinvent it with a preg_replace?

Comment: @Tomalak...that's what I'm trying to do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a regex count the opening brackets and the corresponding closeing brackets, you should use a simple for loop to do that, but you can get the complete string from the first opening bracket to the last closeing one with a greedy expression like: `({.*})`. Note that simple string functions are much faster then regular expressions, so you should use those instead.

Comment: Pointy should get these points since he answered first, but he just left a comment.  Thanks for reiterating.